# Windows XP/7 copy FILE hook

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, delphi-xe2

There's a possibility to hook folder modification operations(copy, delete, rename and so forth), but unfortunately I need hook those operations applied to files. Any thoughts?

Environment:

Delphi XE2, Windows XP/7/2008

Thanks.

Comment: What's the underlying goal? Do you need this at filesystem level, or shell level?

Comment: Undelying goal is pretty trivial. What I need is just intercept copy, delete, rename, move of specific type of files.

Comment: And the other question that I asked?

Comment: Sorry for that. By means of OS shell (Win. Explorer in this case).

Comment: Demos contain copyhook demo, look at it.

Comment: This concept is a very nice thing but unfortunately it works only for folders. I don't know what stopped Microsoft to apply the same concept to files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know two options

1) You can hook the WinAPi functions like [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creating a system wide hook,  wrtting the hook yourself or using a API hook library like [madCodeHook](http://www.madshi.net/) or [Deviare API hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) (I've used both libraries with great results.)

2) Writting a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx).

Comment: WinAPI can also be hooked with Microsoft's Detours library, which comes with an example of such hooks